# Facebook pay UI isn't displaying says we don't accept payments anymore

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

We're using the javascript version of the SDK and finally can get the UI to display something except the message that displays is
"You can't buy things on [our app name] because they don't accept payments anymore. You can keep playing or try a new game"

Can't figure out why it would be displaying this message instead of showing the correct pay dialog with the different pay options such as mobile, cc, paypal, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added 
action: 'purchaseitem' 
to the object being passed to the FB.ui function and now it displays.